# How do I update a listview when my variable changes?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a conditional style using a StyleSelector, so that it changes the color of the playing song to green when the program loads.  However, when the songIndex static variable is changed, I don't know how to make it update. I tried using the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but am not sure how to use it properly or what I am supposed to bind to it. Here is my code....

```
public class HighlightStyleSelector : StyleSelector, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        //List<myMediaInterface> mediaList = new List<myMediaInterface>();
        if (item == MainPage.mediaList[MainPage.songIndex])
        {
            Style style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen)));
            return style;
        }
        else
        {
            var style = Application.Current.Resources["ListViewItemStyle1"] as Style;
            return null;
        }
    }



    public int songIndex
    {
        get { return MainPage.songIndex; }
        set
        {
            songIndex = MainPage.songIndex;
            OnPropertyChanged(songIndex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
     <ListView x:Name="songlistView" SelectionMode="Extended" DoubleTapped="songlistView_DoubleTapped" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF616161" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ManipulationMode="None" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,150,0,558" Tapped="songlistView_Tapped" FontSize="14"  ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource HighlightStyleSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding MainPage.mediaList}">
```

Here is the code for the custom listview

```
    namespace HelloWorld
    {
        public class MyListView : Control
        {
            public int highlightedItem;
            public MyListView()
            {
                this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyListView);
            }

        }
}
```

If I use get; and set; for hightlighted item doesn't work either.  Still says the member highlightedItem is not recognized or is not accessible

Edited 5/25
this is now in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public int songIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return songIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            songIndex = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("songIndex");
        }
    }
```

^^ not sure if this should go with my field declarations?

```
    public void OnPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Here is my code from MainPage.xaml

```
        <ListView x:Name="songlistView" SelectedIndex="{Binding songIndex}" SelectionMode="Extended" DoubleTapped="songlistView_DoubleTapped" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF616161" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ManipulationMode="None" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,150,0,558" Tapped="songlistView_Tapped" FontSize="14"  ItemsSource="{Binding MainPage.mediaList}"><!--ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource HighlightStyleSelector}"-->
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
```

Here is my code 5/26
I'm trying to create a dependencyproperty called highlightedIndex that is identical to selectedIndex, except that it is separate.

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public int highlightedIndex
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(HighlightedProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HighlightedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightedProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MyListView), new PropertyMetadata(0));
}
```

---

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class HighlightStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == MainPage.mediaList[MainPage.songIndex])
        {
            var style = Application.Current.Resources["ListViewItemHighlighted"] as Style;
            Setter setter = new Setter(ListViewItem.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen));
            //Style style = new Style(typeof(ListViewItem));
            style.Setters.Add(setter);
            return style;
        }
        else
        {
            var style = Application.Current.Resources["ListViewItemStyle1"] as Style;
            return style;
        }
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: You `songIndex` property probably throws a `StackOverflowException` form its getter and setter because they both recursively call themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("highlightedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(MyListView), new PropertyMetadata(null, propertyChanged));


    private static void propertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int newValue = (int)e.NewValue;
        ListView lv = (ListView)d;

        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in lv.Items)
        {
            if (lv.Items.IndexOf(lvi) == newValue)
            {
                lvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);
            }
            else
            {
                lvi.Background = new SolidColorBrush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Didn't need the styleselector or any binding

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused because of static properties on `MainPage` you seem to be assigning `songIndex` to and binding `mediaList` to. It would be helpful to see that code as well.

Still, you need to fix your property (assuming `OnPropertyChanged` is implemented correctly):

```
public int songIndex
{
    get { return MainPage.songIndex; }
    set
    {
        // set the assigned value to property backing field
        MainPage.songIndex = value;
        // you need to notify with the name of the property as the argument
        OnPropertyChanged("songIndex");
    }
}
```

Then you can bind to this property like any other with the only difference that the control will be notified when its value changes:

```
<ListView SelectedIndex="{Binding songIndex}" />
```

Comment: The second problem is that even if I use SelectedIndex like you wrote, it will bind but will not update right away.  I can scroll down the listview then back up and the new item will be green, but it won't do it visibly.

Comment: The first problem was that highlightedItem wasn't recognized as a custom property, no idea why

Comment: @Zev `highlightedItem` is not a property in your case, it's a field and as such isn't available from XAML. If you make a property out of it (at least `public int highlightedItem { get; set; }`), it will be recognized. If you want to bind values to it, you'll need to make it a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: @Zev Not sure, why `SelectedIndex` wouldn't update immediately for you. Can you post a vode snippet reproducing the issue? I made a sample before posting the answer and it worked as expected.

Comment: fixed it in 3 lines of code, I love c# but xaml drives me crazy.  Here it is... at least getting the selectedIndex to be bound properly

        Binding binding = new Binding();
           binding.Source = songIndex;
           songlistView.SetBinding(ListView.SelectedIndexProperty,binding);

Comment: so I got the selectedIndex to change immediately... how can I create a duplicate property called highlightedIndex? I'll post what I have above, but it is not updating immediately.  instead it is updating when the listview is scrolled.

Comment: @Zev The 3 lines you pasted should do exactly the same as my line `<ListView SelectedIndex="{Binding songIndex}" />`. You're just creating a binding and assigning it `SelectedIndex` property.

Comment: @Zev Are you sure it's `highlightedIndex` property, that's not changing? I suspect it is the style that only gets reselected when it's scrolled out of view and then back in. It has no idea it should change because a property has changed.

Comment: I think you are right.  I had a hard time figuring out how to update the layout, but I think I got it, of course it was simpler than all this, after many hours trying to get it to work. I learned about dependency properties during the time so that's a plus. Thank you for helping me.